# Unable to display rgb image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I wanted to display rgb image on matlab.

```
image= imread('seker.bmp');
imshow(image);
```

I wrote this lines but it is not working. Why?

Comment: You may want to be a bit more specific about "not working". I suppose you meant you see your image in grayscale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is plausible that you have an "indexed image", as sometimes bmp's are stored as. These instead of color values, store an index from 1 to max(colors) and then a colormap for the colors themselves.

Try:

```
[im,map]= imread('seker.bmp');
imshow(im,map);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the MatLAB documentation, you can use `Image(var)`

If you want to use `imshow`, you should assign an index and a matrice of color.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html